# R multiplying by nonzero elements of a vector

Tags: r

so I'm new to R and have a question about an assignment that I've been given. I have been asked to generate a function that will find the next value in a sequence by "splitting" the current value and adding the product of all nonzero numbers to the previous value (i.e. x1=1032, x2= 1032+ (1)(3)(2)= 1038). this is the code I have so far:

```
split=function(x){
  {
  n=as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(b), "")[[1]])
}
```

this succesfully splits the number into a vector as in split(1032)= 1   0   3   2, and i know that once I get rid of the 0's, the next step is a simple prod(x) command in R, but I cant for the life of me figure out how to kick the zeroes out. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type these into the console for the the help pages on components you'll likely need: `?"=="`, `?"["`.

Maybe a tip to get you started:

```
nums <- 1:10
nums2 <- nums[nums!=5]
```

Note that `!` flips a logical statement. Try `!TRUE`, or `!FALSE`.

It seems to me that you are well on your way to solving this problem. If you need to generate the next X steps of that sequence in numbers, you may need a `for` loop (`?"for"`).

Comment: thanks very much! i solved that problem and am now on to generating the sequence that you mentioned. The for loop advice was crucial!

Comment: No problem. If you have `dat <- c(1,2,3)`, you can add to it by doing `dat[4] <- 4`. So if you have `dat <- c(1)`, then you do `for(i in 2:20){dat[i] <- dat[i-1]+1}` you'll create a sequence that depends on previous values. That should help. Also, if you find an answer helpful, considering up-voting it, or even accepting it! Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you solved it. So for comparison learning, here's how other users might've approached it:

```
seq2 <- function(start, n=1) { res <- numeric(n) 
  nxt <- function(x) {z <- strtoi(strsplit(toString(x),'')[[1]]);x+prod(z[!!z])}
  for(i in 1:n) res[i] <- ifelse(i==1,nxt(start),nxt(res[i-1]));res}
```

Test:

```
seq2(1032)
[1] 1038
seq2(1032, 5)
[1] 1038 1062 1074 1102 1104
```